# How to filter multiple id at textarea and display none other unrelate

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to find `user_id` from all list data.

when i search `user_id`, i will copy `user_id` from `excel` and paste it into `textarea`.

and then the all `user_id` that i chosen must match the `user_id` from all `list data`.

this's my code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea name="" id="paste_your_id"></textarea>
<ul class="ul-list">
  <li data-id="1">Mr. A</li>
  <li data-id="2">Mr. B</li>
  <li data-id="3">Mr. C</li>
  <li data-id="4">Mr. D</li>
  <li data-id="5">Mr. E</li>
  <li data-id="6">Mr. F</li>
  <li data-id="7">Mr. G</li>
</ul>
```

output

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea name="" id="paste_your_id">1
2
3
7</textarea>
<ul class="ul-list">
  <li data-id="1">Mr. A</li>
  <li data-id="2">Mr. B</li>
  <li data-id="3">Mr. C</li>
  <li data-id="4" style="display:none;">Mr. D</li>
  <li data-id="5" style="display:none;">Mr. E</li>
  <li data-id="6" style="display:none;">Mr. F</li>
  <li data-id="7" >Mr. G</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by this simple way

```js
var userList = $(".ul-list").find("li").toArray(); // Store list of userId value here

$("#paste_your_id").on("keyup", function()
{
  var strIds = $(this).val();
  var arrayIds = strIds.split(/[^\d]+/); // Split each item by `whitespace` or `by line` 
  var isFilter = arrayIds.filter(item => item !== "").length > 0;
 
  userList.forEach(item => 
  {
    var id = $(item).data("id").toString();
    var isShow = !isFilter || arrayIds.indexOf(id) !== -1;
    $(item).toggle(isShow);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" id="paste_your_id"></textarea>
<ul class="ul-list">
  <li data-id="1">Mr. A</li>
  <li data-id="2">Mr. B</li>
  <li data-id="3">Mr. C</li>
  <li data-id="4">Mr. D</li>
  <li data-id="5">Mr. E</li>
  <li data-id="6">Mr. F</li>
  <li data-id="7">Mr. G</li>
</ul>
```

**Updated**

1. Your list data can revert to `display:block` when you delete text in `textarea` by this way

   `var isFilter = arrayIds.filter(item => item !== "").length > 0;`
2. Use [.toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) to be more elegant
3. Some comments that I mentioned in JS code to get more performance.

Comment: thank you, but i want to filter multiple id not single id. when i paste id (such as 1 2 3 5) and the list 4 6 7 display:none.

Comment: Yes, you can input value like `1 2 3 5` to see the result

Comment: and when i delete text in textarea, my list data not revert to display:block. how i fix it.

Comment: I've updated my answer, Please take a look @siwakorn

Answer (score 0):

or this...

```js
const regex    = /[A-Za-z0-9]+/g   // accept chars and nums 
  ,   Id_Elm   = document.getElementById('paste_your_id')
  ,   li_List  = document.querySelectorAll('ul.ul-list li')
  ;
function Set_List() {
  let IDs = Id_Elm.value.match(regex) || []
  li_List.forEach(li=>{
    li.style.display = (IDs.includes( li.dataset.id )) ? 'list-item' : 'none'
  })
}
Set_List()

Id_Elm.oninput = Set_List
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="paste_your_id"></textarea>
  <ul class="ul-list">
    <li data-id="1">Mr. A</li>
    <li data-id="2">Mr. B</li>
    <li data-id="3">Mr. C</li>
    <li data-id="4">Mr. D</li>
    <li data-id="5">Mr. E</li>
    <li data-id="6">Mr. F</li>
    <li data-id="7">Mr. G</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your JS code**

```
var arrEleIds = $("li").map(function(){return $(this).attr("data-id");}).get();
    var arrTextVal = $('#paste_your_id').val().replace(/\n/ig, '').split("");
    var difference = arrEleIds .filter(x => !arrTextVal.includes(x));
    difference.forEach(item => 
    {
        $('li[data-id='+item+']').hide();
    })
```

**Your HTML**

```
<textarea name="" id="paste_your_id">1
2
3
7</textarea>
<ul class="ul-list">
  <li data-id="1">Mr. A</li>
  <li data-id="2">Mr. B</li>
  <li data-id="3">Mr. C</li>
  <li data-id="4">Mr. D</li>
  <li data-id="5">Mr. E</li>
  <li data-id="6">Mr. F</li>
  <li data-id="7">Mr. G</li>
</ul>
```